# How to Delete Cached Web Page by URI in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, caching

I want to clear the cache for a particular page (URL). In `Codeigniter`, we don't have this option by default. So, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the solution for my question.
The URI for which I want to clear the cache is **dell-laptops**
My entire URL is http://www.domainname.com/dell-laptops

Method to clear the cache for dell-laptops URI is

```
public function delcach(){
        $gurl = $this->input->get('del');
        $this->output->delete_cache($gurl);
        redirect('/');
    }
```

Now you need to just pass a parameter **del** .And how it looks like is
http://domainname.com/controllername/delcache?del=dell-laptops

Opening above URL will clear the cache page of **dell-laptops**

That's it.
Hope this may help others.